# how to write audio file in flutter web and upload it to firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, audio, flutter-web

currently I am able to record audio and can listen to them, Now I want to Write that audio in a file and upload to firebase.
I cant use the package dart.io for flutter-web for reading a temporary directories can any one help me with this problem having please do let me know.
so then I can write the audio to the file and upload to firebase.

Comment: Can you show how you record the file, or at least what kind of object do you obtain..

Comment: here is firebase storage doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/